# Calculate probability of number based on previous numbers in a non-random sequence

Tags: probability, distributions

I have a large number of number sequences of different lengths consisting of 1s and 0s indicating whether an action has occurred, like:

```
0111001111101

00010001111

01111111011111
```

The digits are not independent, as they represent whether an action has been performed or not, which is dependent on whether that action was carried out on the previous occasion.

What I would like to calculate is the probability of finding a 0 after a sequence of 1, such as the probability of finding a 0 after a single 1, after two 1s, after three 1s, etc, across all these sequences. I would basically like to know whether the probability of a 0 increases or decreases with a longer sequence of 1s. In other words, in this specific instance, does the repeated performance of an action increase or decrease the probability that a competing action will be performed?

I have looked at conditional probabilities but haven't found a solution that matches my problem.

This might be a simple question, but I haven't been able to find the solution by myself so hopefully someone here can help.

Comment: I would suggest that you look at this question: [Predicting Sequence of Integers/Binary Values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299354/predicting-sequence-of-integers-binary-values), which looks like a very similar problem formulation.